# Mostrar posición de elementos repetidos de una lista Python

Tags: python, lista

Estoy haciendo un pequeño desarrollo, y necesito tener la posición de los elementos repetidos de una lista.

Lo que he hecho para esto es lo siguiente:

```
FDE = [1,2,3,4,4,3]
for k in range(6):
   m=[i for i,x in enumerate(FDE) if x==FDE[k]]
print(m)
```

El resultado que me muestra la pantalla es:

> m=[2,5]

En resumen, solo busca el repetido `'3'` pero no el `'4'` que igual está repetido , Lo ideal sería que imprima :

```
m=[2,3,4,5]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay varias formas de hacerlo, una de ellas es usar el método `count` para ver si un elemento se encuentra más de una vez en la lista. No es lo más eficiente pero si conciso:

```
FDE = [1,2,3,4,4,3]
m=[i for i, _ in enumerate(FDE) if FDE.count(x)>1]
print(m)
```

**Salida:**

> [2, 3, 4, 5]

**Edición:**

Como te he comentado, una opción para saber el valor asociado a los índices es usar un diccionario que tenga como clave cada elemento único duplicado y como valor una lista con los índices donde se encuentra.

De nuevo hay varias opciones, una relativamente simple es usar [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). Creamos un diccionario que almacena los elementos únicos como claves y sus índices como valores, posteriormente nos quedamos con aquellas parejas que tengan más de un índice:

```
from collections import defaultdict

FDE = [1,2,3,4,4,3]

aux = defaultdict(list)
for index, item in enumerate(FDE):
    aux[item].append(index)
result = {item: indexs for item, indexs in aux.items() if len(indexs) > 1}
print(result)
```

**Salida:**

> {3: [2, 5], 4: [3, 4]}

Comment: Muchas gracias, pero ahora tengo otra duda ¿Cómo podría saber que los índices 2 y 5 corresponde al repetido '3'?

Comment: @JorgePonti o bien busca los índices `FDE[2]` lo que te retornará 3 o algo mejor, crea un diccionario en el que cada clave sea un elemnto y su valor sea una lista con los indices. Espera un momento, voy a editar la respuesta.

Comment: @JorgePonti mira la edición (al final de la respuesta) a ver si cumple lo que quieres. Saludos.

Comment: Genial, muchas gracias, era lo que buscaba!

Answer (score 2):

Aquí tienes una modificación de la gran solución dada por @FJSevilla que puede se ejecute un poco más rápido, ya que elimina un bucle `for` a cambio de crear un objeto `Counter` a partir de la lista, el cual obtiene un diccionario con el número de ocurrencias (valores) por cada elemento de la lista (claves).

```
from collections import Counter
from collections import defaultdict


lista = [1,2,3,4,4,3]
counts_por_elem = Counter(lista)

indices_por_elem = defaultdict(list)
indices = []   

for indice, elem in enumerate(lista):
  if counts_por_elem[elem] > 1:
    indices.append(indice)  
    indices_por_elem[elem].append(indice)

print(indices_por_elem)
print(indices)
```

Como salida obtienes tanto un diccionario con los índices por elemento, como una lista con los índices de los elementos repetidos.

> `defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {3: [2, 5], 4: [3, 4]})`
>
> `[2, 3, 4, 5]`